# Is there a way to add values to specific columns dynamically in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sql-insert

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`(Apple, orange, banana)
SELECT * FROM `old_table`;
```

This is what I tried. Old table has Apple, orange, banana and New table has Apple, orange, banana, grapes for now but more fruits can be added as column.(Scheduling query and adding fields as columns). So I want to append the results every time the query executes, under their correct respective columns. I want to know if I can insert data from 'old_table' to 'new_table'. With this current approach this is static, Can we insert values to a table according to the schema of another table. I tried like this so that it stays dynamic but this syntax isn't acceptable. Another way I thought was saving the names of columns in an array after each run still didn't work.

```
INSERT INTO `new_table`(SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'old_table')
SELECT * FROM `old_table`;
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: Sharing sample data. A scheduled query is running to get the counts of different fruits for a table. Result row is appended after each run. How should data be inserted if new fruits come in.

[Intial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyiZt.png)

[Final(Expected)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMNpZ.png)

Comment: Can you share sample of data that your have and that you expect? It seems you take the problem by the wrong side.

Comment: Hi, I've made some updates. Let me know if it makes it clear.

Comment: How about to use [MERGE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement) statement, saving the fields for update in variables as per the this [example](https://medium.com/@chekanskiy/bigquery-upsert-with-execute-immediate-8399e9997753)?

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax shows the syntax it supports:

```
INSERT [INTO] target_name
 [(column_1 [, ..., column_n ] )]
 input

input ::=
 VALUES (expr_1 [, ..., expr_n ] )
        [, ..., (expr_k_1 [, ..., expr_k_n ] ) ]
| SELECT_QUERY

expr ::= value_expression
```

The column-list can only be a comma-separated list of fixed identifiers as column names, not a subquery that returns a set of strings to be used as columns.

A subquery can be used only to provide data as input, not identifiers to the column-list.

This is the same as other implementations of SQL. Subqueries return sets of values, not sets of identifiers.

In general, all the identifiers (table names, column names, etc.) must be fixed *before* the query begins executing. The data read during execution cannot change the syntax of the SQL statement itself.

By analogy, what you're asking is like if one could call a function like this:

```
CALL $func(arg1, arg2);
```

With the condition that `$func` depends on the return value of the function. That doesn't make any sense! How can the function be called if the name of the function cannot be determined until the function returns?

So it is the same in SQL. The syntax of the query must be fixed at the time it is parsed, before you begin executing it.